# Can't i set Session in a class file?

Tags: asp.net, session

Why session is null in this even if i set:

```
public class HelperClass
{
    public AtuhenticatedUser f_IsAuthenticated(bool _bRedirect)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["yk"] = DAO.context.GetById<AtuhenticatedUser>(1);
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["yk"] == null)
        {
            if (_bRedirect)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loginPage"] + "?msg=You have to login.");
            }

            return null;
        }

        return (AtuhenticatedUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["yk"];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is this class being called from?

Comment: Think a page which name is AddNews.aspx and think again that i'm validating the user is authenticated or not in AddNews.aspx.cs Page_Load event. Quickly i want to check with "(new HelperClass()).f_IsAuthenticated(true)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually session is not available on application authenticate request.

Session will be available after OnAcquireRequestState call.
Here is application events [call sequence](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030211.asp)

Also, note that session will be available, only if target HttpHandler implements IRequiresSessionState or IReadOnlySessionState, and AuhenticateRequest is usually called for resources like .js or .jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there.  The proper way to reference it is:

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

Or if you've referenced this assembly HttpContext.Current.Session should be good to go.

Comment: Is there any HttpContext not in System.Web namespace?

Comment: @uzay you do not state how this class was created, could be an external dll.  If you just try : Session["Blah"] this won't work.  You need to do: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["blah"].  Or create a wrapper class that wraps all session variables.

Comment: You are right if i call with only Session["blah"] . I'm calling it in aspx.cs class top of methods. Thats why Session is always coming null. ( I think...! )

Answer (score 0):

When i call the method with this code i'm getting error:

```
public partial class AddNews : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private AtuhenticatedUser yk = (new HelperClass()).f_IsAuthenticated(true);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }
```

But when i call the method in Page_Load function it is working

```
public partial class AddNews : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private AtuhenticatedUser yk =new AtuhenticatedUser();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yk = (new HelperClass()).f_IsAuthenticated(true);
    }
```

I think Valera Kolupaev is right ;)